# Basic js object array referencing

Tags: javascript, arrays

This seems like a very simple question so I hope there's a simple solution!

If I have an array of objects:

```
let objArray = [
     {id: 2, name: Bob},
     {id: 4, name: James},
     {id: 3, name: Sally},
     {id: 9, name: Jenny}
]
```

If I then have another variable that tells me which object in the array I want, how would I go about using it?

```
let requiredObj = 2
```

I want to use this variable to return the name 'Bob'. So far I've been doing it by running a for loop and checking each of the ids against the requiredObj. This doesn't seem like the best way to do it, so was hoping there's a 'right way' that I'm not aware of?

Comment: `objArray.find(({ id }) => id === requiredObj)`

Comment: You can use array methods such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find  with your own callback function that determines whether the current object is one you are looking for, if that makes you any happier than writing a loop yourself …

Comment: I don't have a problem writing the loop myself, if that's the right way to do it, just felt very longhand!

Comment: If you just want to take 3rd position(or the position in `requiredobj`) object do `const wantedObject = objArray[requiredObj]`

Comment: I'm not after the item in the third position, I'm looking for the object where id===requiredObj

Comment: user120242 has given you the solution in the first comment…